# Using tilemap.url in Kibana

Tags: maps, visualization, kibana

I am using Kibana 4.5.3 and want to use a different TileServer.  I tried using different tile servers from the following list http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_servers

I added the following line to the kibana.yml file and restarted kibana.
[[ tilemap.url: "http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/$%7Bz%7D/$%7Bx%7D/$%7By%7D.png" ]]

Message from log: 
log   [02:09:29.964] [warning][config] Settings for "tilemap" were not applied, check for spelling errors and ensure the plugin is loaded

It doesn't seems to work. I am sure i am missing something obvious. Please help and advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use almost any tile map service
to configure for example open street map tile service :

```
    tilemap.options.maxZoom: 18
    tilemap.url: http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

at this location : %KIBANA_HOME%\config\kibana.yml